# How to remove default map layer on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, maps, bing-maps

I am trying to improve my old app and make it work good for wp8. Is there any ability to remove default map layer (base layer) or hide it?

When I am adding new TileSource default layer is shown under it for 0.5-1 second. If I zoom labels from default layer are shown near labels from my layer and that creates mess. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to disable the default map layer in the WP8.1 map control.